# Method to get fields and properties by using reflection c#

Tags: c#, reflection

i use two arrays in my code:

```
 var fields = typeof(MyDtoClass).GetProperties();
 var fieldsOfDtoClass = typeof(MyDtoClass).GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
```

but i using this to generate one table and it is possible to out of sync. How can i use one array, but can get in one place properties, and in another place fields this such flags? should i look in GetMembers or smth? any help is much appreciated

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add `MyDtoClass` class definition and expected output array

Comment: `MemberInfo[] fieldsAndProps = typeof(MyDtoClass).GetProperties().OfType<MemberInfo>().Concat(typeof(MyDtoClass).GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)).ToArray();`

Comment: This sounds more like an exercise in reading the online documentation.

Comment: _"using this to generate one table and it is possible to out of sync"_ - By "fields", do you mean database columns? Are you trying to update your table structure when a class changes? Then don't reinvent this complex wheel; use Entity Framework Migrations.

Answer (score 0):

Using class name

```
typeof(YourClass).GetMethod("METHOD_NAME");
typeof(YourClass).GetProperty("PROPERTY_NAME");
```

Using instance

```
yourInstance.GetType().GetMethod("METHOD_NAME");
yourInstance.GetType().GetProperty("PROPERTY_NAME");
```

To enumerate all properties

```
foreach (var property in typeof(YourClass)) {
 Console.WriteLine(property);
}
```

The same way to can enumerate them using Linq

```
typeof(YourClass).GetMethods()
                 .Select(method => method.Name == "GetType");
```

[Official Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/reflection-and-codedom/reflection)

Comment: OP is asking for fields and properties, not methods